# Visual Studio 2010 debugger locks up until debugged program is killed

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, debugging

So in a C# .NET v4 project in VS2010, I've got a debugging issue. Frequently, if not most of the time, the debugger freezes when you try to use it - typically on exceptions, it's usually OK if you try to manually break.

The only way I've discovered to fix this is to kill the debugged program ([projectname].vshost.exe), which unlocks the IDE and executes all the mouse presses and things that happened in its absence.

The main Windows GUI is **not** affected. There is minimal CPU load. Waiting does nothing. The output window (full of "Loaded xxx, symbols loaded") is uneventful. I've read about symbol servers deadlocks, or deadlocks in the GUI, but neither of those are the issue here (the symbol servers are disabled).

Anyone have any ideas? This is giving me a big problem, because I can't effectively debug the program.

Comment: Never heard of this, sure sounds environmental.  Be sure to install SP1.  Limp along by ticking CLR Exceptions in Debug + Exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never did figure this out. Oh well. Limped by with task manager open all summer, but made it through OK.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this could be any number of things.

Most often, I've had this type of thing happen when the program is caught in an infinite loop... but since yours is breaking on exceptions, maybe you could add some exception handling?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the program is not infinitely looping. It's single threaded, even. And the exceptions are bugs... I don't want to handle them, I want to find them and prevent them from happening. That's like the biggest use of a debugger (at least for me).

Comment: By catching the exception, you may be able to prevent your application from crashing and further analyze what's going on via the debugger.  Once you figure out the cause, you can prevent them and move forward.  It's always good to have some sort of error catching! Especially when debugging. :)